# Are vector spaces related to groups?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces

Are vector spaces related to groups?

If so, what are the similarities/differences?

Comment: "Differences" are clear from *definitions*. A vector space must be an abelian group in the first place, again by definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A vector space is an abelian group with some extra structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492548/a-vector-space-is-an-abelian-group-with-some-extra-structure)

Answer (score 3):

A vector space $(V,+, \cdot)$ over a field $k$ is an abelian group $(V,+)$ together with a scalar multiplication $\cdot : k \times V \to V$ which satisfies 4 properties.

So a vector space is a bit more than an abelian group.

Answer (score 1):

A vector space just with vector addition is a group.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a vector space is a quadruple $(V,K,+,\cdot)$, where $V$ is a set, $K$ is a field, and we have operations $+\colon V \times V \to V$ and $\cdot \colon K \times V \to V$ satisfying certain properties. The properties relating to $+$ can be resumed saying that $(V,+)$ is an abelian group. Besides, $K$ is in particular a group, so the operation $\cdot$ is a group action of $K$ over $V$. The distributive properties will relate these two things.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this question is a duplicate [A vector space is an abelian group with some extra structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492548/a-vector-space-is-an-abelian-group-with-some-extra-structure)

To expand on the above answers, the scalar multiplication axioms have as a consequence that, via scalar multiplication, the multiplicative group of the ground field $\mathbb{K}$ (every element of $\mathbb{K}$ except the additive identity $0$) has a group action on the underlying set.

Also, the field of representation theory is (to the best of my knowledge) interested in group actions on the vector space $V$ by the group of invertible linear operators $V \to V$.

So the theory of vector spaces is closely related to that of the theory of [abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) (commutative group operation) and of [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action).